# Sort/filter by date and department

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, react-native

I am new to react-native. Basically, I have created a website which I store my **notification/annoucment** post by each department.

My API: `localhost:8000/api/notifications`

which give me the below result. I can display this into flatlist but how do I `sort/filter` this data so that when I click the button Date:olderst or department: FGO using picker or button and view into the new screen or same screen.

Do I have to create new API that can filter all those

```
[
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "UTAR FIRST NOTIFICATION USING VOYAGER PLUGIN",
        "description": "<p>THIS IS TO TEST IF THIS WORKED IF I ADD PLUGIN</p>",
        "image": "[\"notifications\\\\July2019\\\\CJXexAyUxJEe053uVSqk.png\",\"notifications\\\\July2019\\\\8BED9ewaEH1EHqC4hh3T.jpg\"]",
        "attachment": "[{\"download_link\":\"notifications\\\\July2019\\\\3c8wC2IxHz19cH2oTKUA.docx\",\"original_name\":\"Persona.docx\"},{\"download_link\":\"notifications\\\\July2019\\\\tvZdM6rSsmMn35mTTK5W.docx\",\"original_name\":\"proof.docx\"}]",
        "department": "FGO",
        "link": null,
        "created_at": "2019-07-18 10:11:00",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-18 10:17:27",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "title": "WELCOME TO FIRST FYP PROJECT",
        "description": "<p>THIS IS MY FYP PRO</p>",
        "image": null,
        "attachment": "[]",
        "department": "DCI",
        "link": null,
        "created_at": "2019-07-19 06:21:39",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-19 06:21:39",
        "deleted_at": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Refetch the api with sorting & filter variables, otherwise you would be in trouble with paging.

Comment: its best to handle pagination and ordering on the server so you dont have to load everything into memory when dealing with long lists. You could handle this on the client and order, but only if theres a smaller subset of data and you know you'll have a max

Comment: right now in my Controller i put $notifications = App\Notification::all();
should i change to $notifications = App\Notification::paginate(10);

Answer (score 0):

No need to do this in your API. You can do it in your Js code,

In your case the following approach can be used for sorting (by created_at),

```
myData.sort((a, b) => {
  let dateA = new Date(a.created_at),
    dateB = new Date(b.created_at);
  return dateA - dateB;
});
```

After this if you print your object array to console, you will see it is sorted by created_at variable.

Also filter can be done like this (by department),

```
const newArray = myData.filter(function (item) {
  return item.department === 'FGO';
});
```

After print `newArray` variable you will see new filtered object array.

Comment: but will this happening in my same screen or i need to pass to different screen

Comment: You can do this in your same screen, no need another screen. Just do it after you get your data from your server.

Comment: ok i will try this next week since i will continue doing after my exam, and i will let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.prototype.filter method`:

```
newList = yourList.filter(function (el) {
  return el.department=== 'FGO';
});
```

another generic approach to filter

```
function filterArray(column,value){
    newList = yourList.filter(function (el) {
          return el.column === value;
        });
}
```